# core data with tree structure - return only 1 level

Tags: objective-c, database, core-data

I'm using Core Data and I have a file-folder tree-like structure. So I've created 2 subclasses of NSManagedObject as follows:

**FolderMO**

*Attributes:*
  - FolderName 
*Relationships:*
  - the FolderMO itself (since it can have sub-folders)
  - FileMO (it can have a list of files that belong in the folder)


**FileMO**

*Attributes:*
  - FileName 

The data that I need to store is essentially 3 levels of folders, and then a level of files. On the 1st level I have ~20 Folders, and each Folder has ~20 sub-folders, and each sub-folder has a number of sub-sub-folders, and then finally I have the files that belong in said-folder. I have ~10,000 files total that I need to store. 


***My Question***
Is there a way that I can retrieve only 1 level of my data at a time? ie: Will Core Data let me retrieve only the 1st level of folders to display to the user. Then, if they make a selection, I will retrieve the next level based on their selection? I don't want to have to load all my data into memory at once, especially since the user may not even use this portion of the application.

Thanks!

Sunny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core data wont load all objects until you access them

Comment: When I load my 1st level of FolderMO Objects, each object has a NSSet property that points to the sub-folder or files (this is automatically created by the Relationship that I set up). So doesn't that NSSet get initialized when I retrieve the FolderMO object? In which case, then all the sub-folders are being initialized as soon as I grab my 1st level...

Comment: you should read about core data memory management. Basically your "subfolders" won't be fetched even if you NSLog(@"%@", folder).

Comment: so then do I just need to add a BOOL attribute to my FolderMO, called 'isTopLevel', set it to true for all my 1st level folders, and when I fetch my data from the context I specify to only grab FolderMO's with the isTopLevel == true? And in that way only my 1st level folders will be loaded into memory? Thanks!

Comment: I found the location in the documentation that describes how Core Data doesn't load your relationships until needed: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001803-SW8 Thanks a lot for your help!